# Subsetting a map of maps in clojure

Tags: clojure

I'm quite new to Clojure, so please bear with me. I've been fighting with this seemingly simple task of subsetting a map of maps for a few hours and I'm stumped.

My input 'types' is a collection of strings and 'in-map' has the form like:

```
{2 {3.507276 [1 "Mp2H"], 14.4985235 [1 "MpHpNa"], 21.541099 [1 "MpHpNH4"], 22.4854915 [1 "MpHpK"], 24.020551 [1 "MpACNp2H"], 25.489771 [1 "Mp2Na"], 33.0231235 [1 "2Mp3H2Op2H"], 44.533826 [1 "Mp2ACNp2H"], 65.047101 [1 "Mp3ACNp2H"]}, 1 {6.007276 [1 "MpH"], 11.007276000000001 [1 "2MpH"], 23.033823 [1 "MpNH4"], 27.989771 [1 "MpNa"], 28.033823 [1 "2MpNH4"], 32.989771000000005 [1 "2MpNa"], 38.033489 [1 "MpCH3OHpH"], 43.963707 [1 "MpK"], 47.033826 [1 "MpACNpH"], 48.963707 [1 "2MpK"], 52.033826 [1 "2MpACNpH"], 69.016321 [1 "MpACNpNa"], 74.016321 [1 "2MpACNpNa"], 88.060376 [1 "Mp2ACNpH"]}, 3 {2.673942666666667 [1 "Mp3H"], 10.001440966666667 [1 "Mp2HpNa"], 17.328939336666668 [1 "Mp2NaH"], 17.328943366666667 [1 "MpHp2Na"], 24.65643766666667 [1 "Mp3Na"], 27.978229666666667 [1 "Mp2KpH"]}}
```

I want subset 'in-map' to only those inner items that match the 'types'

Such that if our 'types' are `["Mp2H" "MpH" "MpNH4" "Mp3H"]` it will return:
 `{2 {3.507276 [1 "Mp2H"]}, 1{6.007276 [1 "MpH"], 23.033823 [1 "MpNH4"]}, 3{2.673942666666667 [1 "Mp3H"]}}`

This is my current attempt:

```
(map (fn [[id multiple-items]]
    [id (->> multiple-items
                (filter (fn [[_ single-type]]
                (in? types (get single-type 1)))
                ))]
in-map))
```

Currently this is returning `object[clojure.core$map$fn__4549 0x47257bf1 "clojure.core$map$fn__4549@47257bf1"]`. I had an earlier attempt that worked to subset but the format of the output did not match the input which looks as follows:

```
(map (fn [[id multiple-items]]
       [id (filter (fn [[_ single-type]]
               (in? types (get mol-adduct 1)))
                    multiple-items)])
 in-map))
```

This returns:

```
([2 ([3.507276 [1 "Mp2H"]])] [1 ([6.007276 [1 "MpH"]] [23.033823 [1 "MpNH4"]])] [3 ([2.673942666666667 [1 "Mp3H"]])])
```

Which is not the same format as the input.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure it out with some extra Google Fu and playing around! The solution:

```
(into {} 
  (map (fn [[id multiple-items]]
    [id (into {} 
          (filter (fn [[_ single-type]]
                    (in? types (get mol-adduct 1)))
          multiple-items))])
  in-map))
```